# Handling and bypassing "TypeError: 'NoneType' " in python code

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, typeerror

So I have this code which prints out the minimum cost and restaurant id for the item/items. The customer doesnt want to visit multiple restaurants. So for example if he asks for "A,B" then the code should print shop which offers them both , instead of scattering the user requirement around different restaurants (even if some restaurant is offering it cheap).

The error is basically coming because both the item ('burger' and 'D') are not available **"together"** at any of the two restaurants (1 & 2). But instead of throwing such long error , I'd simply like to print "One of item not available at a resto" etc.

Other such error throwing cominations are `solver(shop_text,['tofulog', 'D'])` , because 'tofulog' is only available at restaurant_1, wheras 'D' is available only at restaurant_2.

```
def build_shops(shop_text):
    shops = {}
    for item_info in shop_text:
        shop_id,cost,items = item_info.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        cost = float(cost)
        items = items.split('+')

        if shop_id not in shops:
            shops[shop_id] = {}
        shop_dict = shops[shop_id]

        for item in items:
            if item not in shop_dict:
                shop_dict[item] = []
            shop_dict[item].append([cost,items])
    return shops


def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    all_possible = []
    first_item = items[0]
    if first_item in shop:
        for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
            #print "items,combo=",items,combo
            sub_set = [x for x in items if x not in combo]
            #print "sub_set=",sub_set
            price_sub_set,solution = solve_one_shop(shop, sub_set)
            solution.append([price,combo])
            all_possible.append([price+price_sub_set, solution])

    if all_possible:
        cheapest = min(all_possible, key=(lambda x: x[0]))
        return cheapest


def solver(input_data, required_items):
    shops = build_shops(input_data)
    result_all_shops = []
    for shop_id,shop_info in shops.iteritems():
        this_shop = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
        if this_shop is not None:
            (price, solution) = this_shop
            result_all_shops.append([shop_id, price, solution])

    shop_id,total_price,solution = min(result_all_shops, key=(lambda x: x[1]))
    print('SHOP_ID=%s' % shop_id)
    sln_str = [','.join(items)+'(%0.2f)'%price for (price,items) in solution]
    sln_str = '+'.join(sln_str)
    print(sln_str + ' = %0.2f' % total_price)


shop_text = open('input-1.csv','rb')    
solver(shop_text,['burger', 'D'])
```

**=====input-1.csv=====restaurant_id, price, item**

```
1,2.00,burger
1,1.25,tofulog
1,2.00,tofulog
1,1.00,chef_salad
1,1.00,A+B
1,1.50,A+CCC
1,2.50,A
2,3.00,A
2,1.00,B
2,1.20,CCC
2,1.25,D
```

**======OUTPUT=======**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "26mar_cheap.py", line 106, in <module>
    final_out(restaurant_read,sys.argv[2:])
  File "26mar_cheap.py", line 92, in final_out
    this_resto = requirement_one_restaurant(shop_info, required_items)
  File "26mar_cheap.py", line 77, in requirement_one_restaurant
    cost_sub_set,solution = requirement_one_restaurant(shop, sub_set)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback doesn't seem to be relevant to the code you've posted: the error is in `requirement_one_restaurant` but you've only posted `solve_one_shop`.

However, assuming the pattern of the code is similar, you're apparently doing some sort of recursive call. When you do this you need to ensure that all possible paths return a value. In `solve_one_shop`, for example, if `all_possible` is still empty by the end of the function then nothing will be returned, which will lead to the NoneType error.